# Rest Template request aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, resttemplate

I'm trying to hit an endpoint in another service registered in my Eureka Server called "user-service", using rest template. The endpoint in the other service will return all the data from the database, as you can see here:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public Page<User> findAll() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

My "client-service" is trying to use the "user-service"'s endpoint with this code.
UserClient:

```
public List<UsuarioVo> getUsers(){
    HttpEntity headers = new HttpEntity(getHeaders());
    String url = urlUserClient + "/users";
    ResponseEntity<List<UserVo>> result= restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, headers , new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<UserVo>>() {});
    return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(result.getBody(), TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, UserVo.class));
}

private HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("username", request.getHeader("username"));
    return headers;
}
```

ClientService:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@PreAuthorize("@searchRole.hasPermission('GET')")
public ResponseEntity<List<ProdutividadeDTO>> getProdutividade(){
    List<UserVo> users = pessoaServiceClient.obterUsuarios();
}
```

When I hit the enpoint, my "user-service" throw an exception after executing all the sql codes: `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine... Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`
Someone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Is your query taking a lot of time to execute? See [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852152/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine-tomca) (and you know you're free to search with your exception too, it's not like you don't have access to Google).

Comment: Well, so if it's a basic fact that I do have access to google then do you really need to mention that? I already saw that answer and already tried this solution but it didn't worked for me. I put this code `server.connection-timeout=999000` in the `application.properties` on both and got the same issue. When I hit the endpoint directly by Postman on the "user-service" he takes 600-700MS to answer so, I guess isn't a lot of time right?

Comment: But you didn't mention that you saw the solution and tried it, so I couldn't have known it. Since you're the one with the problem, it's in your best interest to give as much information as you can. In any case, you have a `ClientAbortException`, so you'll need to find out why the client is breaking the connection if it's not a timeout.

Comment: Actually I know that, my fault there! I just felt your comment was a little harsh, in other questions here the people said something like "You already tried this?". Whatever, I think that's some kind of permission that is missing cause if I send the same request to another endpoint (I'm using "/users" to my controller and "/{id}" to make the search by id) it works perfectly! So, I'm thinking this is a security thing of Spring Boot. I'm reading the documentation now but didn't find anything yet!

Comment: I'd probably monitor the network traffic to see what's happening when the client aborts, since that's the root of the problem.

Comment: I'll search if there's another way to retreive this information, insetead of using Rest Template I'll use other thing. Looks like Spring Boot have a native configuration to communicate between services, or Eureka has this feature, if they have I'll use it! The funny thing is, this was working in a few days ago. I'll need to track down what has changed that made it stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locally I fixed! The thing is, in my project we use a super class called OperationService where we have all the generic GET, POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE calls. I was calling the GET without any especific URL eg: "users/loadall", when I build up an endpoint called "loadAll" with this URL and hit it, in my local configuration it worked perfectly! The problem now is in my server but that's other problem probably. Thanks you all!