# Spring boot end point to export file - established connection was aborted

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, download

I have simple end point via spring-boot app that is used to export zip as InputStreamResource.

My questions are:

1. Why does it fail to get response?
2. The zip was already generated and hence it should not be timeout problem? Simply saying, the result should be returned in a few seconds.
3. When I want to export single file in same approach then it is possible. Is possible that the issue is related somehow with zip format?
4. What can I do to fix it?

```
ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1862)
    at com.fa
...
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/data/zip/{id}', method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getZip(@PathVariable Long id) throws IOException {
   try {
       // service.getResult(id) returns ZIP that is included in Map<Long, InputStream>
       InputStream result = service.getResult(id); /
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.headers("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "test.zip");
       return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType('application/zip').body(new InputStreamResource(result));
   }
}
```

Checked [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852152/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine-tomca) but it does not help. Just for reference. Thanks for any positive direction.

Comment: try to simplify and locate the problem. (a) replace `result` in response with empty `ByteArrayInputStream`. (b) try in debug mode to read (log) full content of your `result` before sending response. (c) disable anti-virus software if any.